# Moving points on curve to raycast hit position - Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have a bezier circle around a cube object.
I use *Instance on Points* to find 10 points on the curve, and instance a placeholder sphere mesh on them.

[image: spheres on curve around the cube mesh]

I would like to have each point raycast toward a specific target (the cube) and move the spheres on the hit points of the cube.

This is my basic setup[image: basic geometry node setup]

If I connect the set position node, instead of moving the spheres, they disappear as if no hit appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this task, you would only need to pay attention to the *Ray Direction*:

[image]

Instantiate your spheres, but do NOT transform them with `Realize Instances`. Instead use the `Raycast` node directly. This way the *Source Position* is the position of the instances.

As *Ray Direction* you use the direction you get when you subtract the positions of the instances from the position of your cube.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: thank you ! I was under the impression that I needed `Realize Instances` to have the single items position